Change cache-control max-age-48000 to cache-control max-age=48000 in response header
I need to change the hyphen to equal to for my cache-control max-age
I am not getting where it is coming from kindly help me with it.
I checked iis config as well but nothing found there.
Thanks in advance.

Could you please share the relevant code and configuration the place where you are getting the cache-control max-age-48000? Usually to modify the Cache-Control header from max-age-48000 to max-age=48000, you need to identify where this header is being set. This can be done either in your application code or within your server's configuration.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically note that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to show some effort to solve the problem, and ask a specific question about your code.


Change cache-control max-age-48000 to cache-control max-age=48000 in
response header

It would be nicer if you could have shared your relevant code snippet or how you are currently setting your response header.
Apart from that, in order to change your response header pattern from max-age-48000 to max-age=48000 this can either be achieved in different ways.
You could do that using middleware or in Web.config within IIS
Let's have a look, how we could implement using asp.net core middleware.
    public class CacheControlMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CacheControlMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
               
                context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=48000";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
app.UseMiddleware<CacheControlMiddleware>();

Output:


Note: If need additional information, please refer to this official document here for middleware and IIS web config.

The incorrect header likely isn't coming from IIS configuration directly. It could be set by:

An application you're using.
A server-side script generating the header.
A caching layer (like a CDN) configured incorrectly.


screenshot
my project isn't using any middleware service

That's okay, if you want to modify max-age-48000 to max-age=48000  either you should find the palce where it has been set or use the middleware to override it the way you need.
